# Connect React Client running on local PC to Kubernetes Cluster on Azure

Tags: reactjs, azure, kubernetes

I have 2 deployments + services running on Azure: react client and nodejs auth.
I have registered a public IP on Azure which I added to my windows host file (= `myexample.com`).
Typing the URL in the browser, the client opens and requests go to auth service as expected.

Now I want to run the client locally (with `npm start`) but connect to auth service still running on Azure.
I removed the client from the cloud deployment (= the deployment+the service) and use the domain (=`myexample.cloud`) as the base URL in my axios client in my React client. To confirm, on Azure my ingress-nginx-controller of type Load_Balancer shows the aforementioned public IP as its external IP plus ports 80:30819/TCP,443:31077/TCP.
When I ran the Client locally, it shows the correct request URL (`http://myexample.cloud/api/users/signin`) but I get a `403 Forbidden` answer.

What am I missing? I should be able to connect to my cloud service by using the public IP? There error is caused by my client because Azure is not putting road blocks in place. I mean it is a pubic IP, correct?

**Update 1**

Just to clarify, the `403 Forbidden` is not caused by me trying to sign in with incorrect credentials. I have another `api/users/health-ckeck` route that is giving me the same error

My cloud ingress deployment. I have also tried to remove the client part (last 7 lines) to no effect.

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: ingress-service
  annotations:
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
    kubernetes.io/ingress.class: nginx
spec:
  rules:
    - host: myexample.cloud
      http:
        paths:
          - path: /api/users/?(.*)
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: auth-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
          - path: /
            pathType: Prefix
            backend:
              service:
                name: client-srv
                port:
                  number: 3000
```

my client cloud deployment+service that worked when client was running in cloud

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: client
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: client
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: client
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: client
          image: client
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: client
spec:
  selector:
    app: client
  ports:
    - name: client
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

my auth deployment + service

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: auth
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: auth
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: auth
    spec:
      containers:
        - name: auth
          image: auth
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: auth
spec:
  selector:
    app: auth
  ports:
    - name: auth
      protocol: TCP
      port: 3000
      targetPort: 3000
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem was actually `CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin'`
but my browser did not tell me.
After switching from Chrome to Firefox, the problem became apperant.
I had to add annotations to my ingress controller as described here: [express + socket.io + kubernetes Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57749872/express-socket-io-kubernetes-access-control-allow-origin-header)